Add links in dash-leaflet geojson popups that have a callback when clicked
I've created an interactive map using dash-leaflet using the geojson module (hope module is the right word).
I have created custom html popups for each marker. I need to incorporate links in the popup that trigger a callback so that the app can fetch a file and provides a download through the user's browser.
def create_geojson(data):
    features = []
    for _, row in data.iterrows():
        feature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [row['longitude'], row['latitude']]
            },
            "properties": {
                "price": row['price'],
                "description": row['desc'],
                "popup": create_popup(....) # Multiple keys for row are used to generate HTML code for each popup
            }
        }
        features.append(feature)
    return {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features}

ChatGPT tells me that callbacks are not supported within the popup content. If this is true, can I use some hack to achieve the functionality?

"Callbacks are not supported within the popup content" : actually it depends whether the popup is part of the layout (ie. as a Dash component, on which you can register callbacks), or not.
If it's the case, you can achieve this using dl.Popup (or dbc.Modal), html.Button (instead of links) and dcc.Download components.
Otherwise, you can still use custom html to build the popup content with download links, and route the links to a specific function (NB. by default Dash uses Flask server, ie. app.server is a Flask instance, @see URL Route Registrations), for example :
@app.server.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return flask.send_from_directory(some_dir, filename)

where some_dir is a directory path that filename must be located under, relative to the current application’s root path if not absolute.

This sounds like the right way. Can you provide an example where the popup is a dash component? Currently I'm defining the popup html in the properties section of the geojson. I also couldn't find any modules in dcc which can serve as a popup, my limited search turned up mostly sliders, forms etc.

You will find some examples following the links I provided for each component (note dbc.Modal is a Dash Bootstrap Component). I would need to see a mwe to determine if the callback solution is actually feasible and, if it's the case, provide you a more detailed example. You "created custom html popups for each marker" but currently it's not clear what should trigger the opening of the modal (ie. you also need a callback to display the modal content).

I've added the function that creates the geojson structure, including the popup content. Currently, clicking a marker opens the associated popup content but I can't add any callback function (link, button etc) in the popup that would actually work (or maybe I don't know how to, can I add a html.button inside the popup html and expect it to work with callbacks?). In general, I would expect the Modal to replace the popup, or if that's too complicated (aligning the Modal position attached to a marker), it's also acceptable for me to open some kind of sidebar when a marker is clicked

I just realized the popup in leaflet is a regular Dash component (@see dl.Popup, forget dbc.Modal), but you still need to explicitly make it part of the layout instead of having popups registered in geojson data : I would add an hidden dl.Popup in the layout (ie. one popup for all markers), register a callback with geojson's clickData property as Input, use these data in the callback to set popup content and position accordingly as outputs. In the popup content you can add a button that will trigger the download callback.

Please provide a working dash app with context and data if you need a more detailed example. Also note the routing option is a solid solution, might be easier in your situation.
